# Why is datatables setting an automatic table width when using bServerSide=true?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

For some reason, after parsing the table data, the html table gets autostyled with (see style):

```
<table id="datatable_user" style="width: 1649px;">
```

The width always depends on the window size. Strange thing is that it only happens when the data comes from an external resource:

```
{
"bServerSide": true,
"sAjaxSource": "data.json"
}
```

Also, I'm using jquery.datatables.js and datatables.bootstrap.js.

Comment: Does the data make it overflow or the table just autosize to the parent DOM element?

Comment: @G.Mendes the data is very short. The table gets autosized, literally with a style="width: XXXpx;" after the json response has been parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
"bAutoWidth": false
```